# Do I need a transit visa for changing airplane in San Juan airport?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, puerto-rico, afghan-citizens, sju

I am an Afghan citizen and I have a flight from Sao pula to Dominica via Puerto Rico.
I have a 23h stay.
Do I need a transit visa?

Comment: There are no scheduled flights between São Paulo and San Juan, Puerto Rico. Are you sure this is the right route?

Comment: @pnut It is not one of the United States but it is part of the USA for almost all practical purposes that would concern a traveller. You could make a similar argument that Washington DC is not in any US State but like Puerto Rico it is subject to the exclusive sovereignty and jurisdiction of the US Federal Government.

Comment: @pnuts Puerto Rico is a territory of the USA.

Comment: If you have one ticket, booked with one airline, this is a question for the airline.  They should only book you for a route that is viable.

Comment: @aparente001 Nope. it's the passenger's responsiblity to find out. And the US does not have exit border checks, so the departure gate area is not an interantional transit zone - thus, he'll Need to enter the US and will Need a C1 visa to do this

Comment: Not all US territories have identical customs and immigration policies, i.e. travel between them is not borderless. Guam has its own set of additional visa waiver countries. In PR and the USVI you are subject to CBP inspection before boarding a plane to the US mainland (though I think that is more about customs than immigration).

Comment: @DavidRicherby If you know for a fact that all US territories have the same rules as the rest of the USA on this, then **that knowledge answers the question**, and should be put as an answer, like Zach Lipton has done. It doesn't help anyone if people just hit "close" because they know something the asker doesn't, leaving the asker and others guessing.

Comment: @pnuts Puerto Rico has been part of the USA since 1898. What are you talking about?

Comment: @pnuts I have no idea why you're persisting in this, but spreading incorrect information is not helpful and will confuse and mislead people. Please stop now.

Comment: @pnuts Which part of "Puerto Rico is an unincorporated territory of the United States" (from the first paragraph of the Wikipedia entry you linked) causes you to believe that Puerto Rico "is a distinct country".

Comment: @pnuts Then you do not understand what it means to be a territory of a country.

Comment: @pnuts Whether or not I have heard of Bermuda is irrelevant to the question of whether Puerto Rico is an independent country.

Comment: @pnut Nothing in the article you link suggests that Puerto Rico is a country. Indeed the article even cites the landmark 1901 case where the US Supreme Court explicitly says, "Puerto Rico is not a foreign country". Nor would many people consider Bermuda to be a country (a quick google search finds zero reliable sources for that assertion), although it is given a great deal more latitude in its internal affairs by the UK than Puerto Rico is permitted by the US federal government.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44731/discussion-on-question-by-sher-mohamad-do-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-changing-air).

Answer (score 12):

Puerto Rico is a United States territory and [the same rules for immigration purposes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21727/do-i-need-an-esta-for-changing-airplanes-in-puerto-rico) apply as in any US state (this is not true of every US territory, but it is the case for Puerto Rico). Just as transits at mainland US airports require you to go through immigration, all transits at San Juan require you to go through US immigration. You will need a US visa.

Furthermore, according to sleepininairports.net, [you cannot sleep overnight airside at San Juan Airport](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/usa/sanjuan.htm) and there are mixed reports as to whether sleeping overnight in the airport is allowed at all.

Comment: @pnuts I don't feel that strongly about it really, but since it's US immigration law and a US visa that applies, I thought it fits. Feel free to remove if you disagree.

Comment: @pnuts Puerto Rico has been part of the United States since 1898. If you arrive there on an international flight, it will certainly be US immigration you deal with.

Comment: Note that Puerto Rico being a US territory does not imply that the same rules for immigration apply to it. American Samoa is a US territory and regular US immigration law does not apply to it, and it has its own rules.

Comment: @user102008 I added a note to clarify that some territories may be different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you Need a C1 (transit) visa because the US has no exit border controls, so everyone arriving there needs to enter the country, collect luggage, drop it off and go back through security